# How do I remove table borders in iText7 .NET?

Tags: vb.net, itext7

I'm trying to remove borders around cells in a table using iText7 in .NET. I've tried SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER) every where with no luck. See code and pdf below:

```
Dim writer As New PdfWriter(dest)
Dim pdf As New PdfDocument(writer)
Dim pdfdoc As New Document(pdf)
pdfdoc.SetMargins(5, 5, 5, 15)
Dim CLSHdr As New Table({100, 470, 370}) : CLSHdr.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)

Dim AddTbl As New Table(1) : AddTbl.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)

Dim pdfCell As New Cell : pdfCell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
Dim logo As New Image(ImageDataFactory.Create("Image.jpg")) : logo.Scale(0.5, 0.5)
pdfCell.Add(logo)
CLSHdr.AddCell(pdfCell)
CLSHdr.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
CLSHdr.AddCell(New Cell().Add(New Paragraph("  "))).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
CLSHdr.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
pdfCell = New Cell().Add(New Paragraph("First Row"))
pdfCell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetMaxHeight(16)
AddTbl.AddCell(pdfCell)
pdfCell = New Cell().Add(New Paragraph("Second Row"))
pdfCell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetMaxHeight(16)
AddTbl.AddCell(pdfCell)
pdfCell = New Cell().Add(New Paragraph("Third Row"))
pdfCell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetMaxHeight(16)
AddTbl.AddCell(pdfCell)
pdfCell = New Cell().Add(New Paragraph("Fourth"))
pdfCell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetMaxHeight(16)
AddTbl.AddCell(pdfCell)
AddTbl.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
CLSHdr.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
CLSHdr.AddCell(AddTbl).SetWidth(500).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
pdfdoc.Add(CLSHdr).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
pdfdoc.Close()
```

Resulting pdf:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While I'm working with tables, initially I'm having the same issue when I don't want to have the border. After some try and error, I found out that you'll have to call:

```
SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
```

before you add the Paragraph. Hope it helps.